# Firebase Phone Auth Not Workng in Vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Below is the error shown

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.eval (Login.vue?7463:65)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js?1157:5429)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js?1157:5233)
```

Below is my code

```
mounted() {
    window.$("#submit").click(function() {
      var input = window
        .$("#inputPhone")
        .val()
        .trim();
      if (input.length > 13 || input.length < 10 || isNaN(input)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid phone no");
      } else {
        window.$("#phone").hide();
        window.$("#code").show();

        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
          "submit",
          {
            size: "invisible"
          }
        );

        //         window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth().RecaptchaVerifier('submit', {
        //   'size': 'invisible',
        //   'callback': function(response) {
        //     // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
        //     console.log(response);
        //   }
        // });
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithPhoneNumber(input, window.recaptchaVerifier)
          .then(function(confirmationResult) {
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            console.log(confirmationResult);
          });
        window.$("#login").click(function() {
          var inp = window
            .$("")
            .val()
            .trim();
          if (inp.length === 0) {
            alert("Please enter code");
          } else {
            var myFunction = function() {
              window.confirmationResult
                .confirm(inp)
                .then(function(result) {
                  console.log(result);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            };
            myFunction();
          }
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Please look into my code and help me.
Below is the code of config i imported
Below is the code of config i imported
Below is the code of config i imported
Below is the code of config i imported
Below is the code of config i imported

```
import { firebase } from "../firebase";
```

Error is in below lines of code as per chrome developer tools

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      "submit",
      {
        size: "invisible"
      }
    );
```

Comment: firebase is undefined, did you add the config object?

Comment: yes i add the config

Comment: Try debugging. In Chrome, right click -> Inspect -> Sources and then add breakpoints and debug

Comment: i am unable to debug and the error is still coming

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly set up Auth?
[Setup Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn)

```
<body>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you enabled phone auth sign-in method in firebase console?

Comment: you have mentioned that error is thrown when you initialise RecaptchaVerifier, check when it is initialised, i.e. it should be initialised after you have initialised your firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Comment: i have imported firebase first and then initialized the RecaptchaVerifier

Comment: if you are using Google Chrome, open your page open up Developer Tools by pressing F12, in console first type firebase if it throws error firebase is not initialised, check why is it not initialised, if it shows you object data all is good, second type firebase.auth if it give an error then Firebase Auth is definitely not initialised.